# gRPC binary not found by Hyperledger composer-cli

Tags: hyperledger, grpc, hyperledger-composer

After completing full installation of Hyperledger as per their documentation [mentioned here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/installing/development-tools), when I execute `composer-playground`, I get error saying `The gRPC binary module was not installed. This may be fixed by running "npm rebuild"`

This happens even after I run `npm install` and `npm rebuild`.

Full stacktrace is metioned below:

```
error: [Hyperledger-Composer] :ConnectionProfileManager :getConnectionManagerByTyp Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection type "hlfv1". The gRPC binary module was not installed. This may be fixed by running "npm rebuild"
Original error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v59-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'-The gRPC binary module was not installed. This may be fixed by running "npm rebuild"
Original error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v59-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'-The gRPC binary module was not installed. This may be fixed by running "npm rebuild"
Original error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v59-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'-The gRPC binary module was not installed. This may be fixed by running "npm rebuild"
Original error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v59-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'-The gRPC binary module was not installed. This may be fixed by running "npm rebuild"
Original error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v59-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'-The gRPC binary module was not installed. This may be fixed by running "npm rebuild"
Original error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v59-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'-The gRPC binary module was not installed. This may be fixed by running "npm rebuild"
Original error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v59-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'
    at Promise.resolve.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/composer-common/lib/connectionprofilemanager.js:144:42)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using node V9. Composer only works with Node V8. Suggest you use nvm https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm to manage your node installations. Use it to install node 8 (nvm install 8). Then you will need to npm install composer again.